# .stop() for a setTimeout function

Tags: jquery, queue

I'm making a custom sub-menu animation that brings the opacity up for each item on my list. It all works well, but the problem comes when the user interacts faster than the animation itself. The usual way I deal with it is to put .stop() in my function and job done. But since I'm dealing with a .each() animation, I'm not quite sure what to do.

here's the code:

```js
  var $temFilho = $('#menu-item-24'),
   $subMenu = $temFilho.children('.sub-menu'),
   $subli = $subMenu.children('li'),
   $subliC = $subli.length;

  $temFilho.mouseenter(function abreMenu () {
   $subMenu.addClass('menuAberto');
   $subli.each(function(i) {
    $(this).stop().delay(i*100).animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
   });
  });

  $temFilho.mouseleave(function fechaMenu () {
   $($subli.get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
    $(this).stop().delay(i*200).animate({opacity: 0}, 600);
   });
   setTimeout(function () {
    $subMenu.removeClass('menuAberto');
   }, ($subli.length*200)+600)
  });
```

```css
nav.nav {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "adobe-caslon-pro",serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
nav.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-right: solid 2px #eee;
}
nav.nav li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
nav.nav li.menu-item-has-children:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 10px;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #eee;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu.menuAberto {
  display: block;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li a {
  display: block;
  border-top: solid 1px #eee;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #fff;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li:first-child a {
  border-top: none;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
      <ul><li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children menu-item-24"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/">News</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
 <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/gemas/">Gemas</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/joias/">Joias</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-27" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/moda/">Moda</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-28" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/variados/">Variados</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-29" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/artouro/">Artouro</a></li>
 <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-30" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/curiosidades/">Curiosidades</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/ebooks/">Ebooks</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/pagina-exemplo/">Contato</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-23"><a href="http://loja.artouro.com.br/">Loja Virtual</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-22"><a href="http://artouro.com.br/">Site</a></li>
</ul>     </nav>
```

Comment: You can use `.stop(true)`... to clear the queue

Comment: If you can share a demo of the problem... we could have a better understanding

Comment: _"But since I'm dealing with a queued animation, I'm not quite sure what to do."_ `queue` not appear utilized at `js` at Question ?

Comment: Ok, @ArunPJohny, did both added the .stop() as well as completed the snippet to be workable. In fact, the .each() bit seems to be solved, the only problem is now the setTimeout bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear the timer on mouseenter

```js
var $temFilho = $('#menu-item-24'),
  $subMenu = $temFilho.children('.sub-menu'),
  $subli = $subMenu.children('li'),
  $subliC = $subli.length,
  temFilhoTimer;

$temFilho.mouseenter(function abreMenu() {
  $subMenu.addClass('menuAberto');
  $subli.stop(true).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 100).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 400);
  });
  clearTimeout(temFilhoTimer)
});

$temFilho.mouseleave(function fechaMenu() {
  $($subli.get().reverse()).stop(true).each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 200).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 600);
  });
  temFilhoTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    $subMenu.removeClass('menuAberto');
  }, ($subli.length * 200) + 600)
});
```

```css
nav.nav {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "adobe-caslon-pro", serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
nav.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  border-right: solid 2px #eee;
}
nav.nav li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
nav.nav li.menu-item-has-children:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 10px;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #eee;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu.menuAberto {
  display: block;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li a {
  display: block;
  border-top: solid 1px #eee;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #fff;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li:first-child a {
  border-top: none;
}
nav.nav li ul.sub-menu li:last-child a {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-has-children menu-item-24"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/">News</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-25" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/gemas/">Gemas</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-26" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/joias/">Joias</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-27" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/moda/">Moda</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-28" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/variados/">Variados</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-29" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/artouro/">Artouro</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-30" style="opacity: 0;"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/category/curiosidades/">Curiosidades</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/ebooks/">Ebooks</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://localhost/artouro/pagina-exemplo/">Contato</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-23"><a href="http://loja.artouro.com.br/">Loja Virtual</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-22"><a href="http://artouro.com.br/">Site</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ooooh! It makes a lot of sense! Thank you! And sorry for the weird element names.